# wfs request on different namespaces - first one successfull, second one crashes

Tags: geoserver, wfs

first request:

```
http://mygeoserver/Namespace1/wfs
```

with post-body

```
 <wfs:GetFeature xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<wfs:Query typeName="feature:myfeature" srsName="EPSG:31466" xmlns:feature="Namespace1"></wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

second request:

```
http://mygeoserver/Namespace2/wfs
```

with post-body

```
 <wfs:GetFeature xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<wfs:Query typeName="feature:myfeature" srsName="EPSG:31466" xmlns:feature="Namespace2"></wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

As you can see, both requests differ in Namespace only.

However:

first response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:ows="http://www
.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns
:Namespace1="Namespace1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" numberOfFeatures="14569"
 timeStamp="2016-04-28T14:43:20.233Z" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://mygeoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd Namespace1 http://mygeoserver/Namespace1
/wfs?service=WFS&amp;version=1.1.0&amp;request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;typeName=Namespace1%3Amyfeature"
><gml:featureMembers><Namespace1:myfeature gml:id="myfeature.1">...
```

second response

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:ows="http://www
    .opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
xmlns:Namespace1="Namespace1"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" numberOfFeatures="2460"
     timeStamp="2016-04-28T14:28:21.292Z" xsi:schemaLocation="Namespace2 http://mygeoserver/Namespace2/wfs?service=WFS&amp;version=1.1.0&amp;request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;typeName=Namespace2%3Amyfeature http
    ://www.opengis.net/wfs http://mygeoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"><gml:featureMembers
    ><null:myfeature gml:id="myfeature.1">...
```

As you can see, I get

`xmlns:Namespace1="Namespace1"` and `<null:myfeature gml:id="myfeature.1">`
 where I expect 
`xmlns:Namespace2="Namespace2"` and `<Namespace2:myfeature gml:id="myfeature.1">`

Looks like there is some mess going on in geoserver, probably some caching issue.

Obviously, the secnod request leads to an error:

```
XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace Location: moz-nullprincipal:{b67f9340-397a-4f4e-b041-f71627db6f56} Line Number 1, Column 722:

...r/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"><gml:featureMembers><null:myfeature gml:id="myfeature...
```

After I restart my geoserver and do the first request on Namespace2, it will be Namespace1 that crashes.

To me, it looks like there must be something weird going on in the geoserver's cache.

Any ideas?

---

the describeFeature request return

`<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="Namespace1"><xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://mygeoserver/schemas/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"/><xsd:complexType name="myfeatureType"><xsd:complexContent><xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType"><xsd:sequence><xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="geom" nillable="true" type="gml:MultiSurfacePropertyType"/><xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="myproperty" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/></xsd:sequence></xsd:extension></xsd:complexContent></xsd:complexType><xsd:element name="myfeature" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="Namespace1:myfeatureType"/></xsd:schema>`

and
`<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="Namespace2"><xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http:/mygeoserver/schemas/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"/><xsd:complexType name="myfeatureType"><xsd:complexContent><xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType"><xsd:sequence><xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="geom" nillable="true" type="gml:MultiSurfacePropertyType"/><xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="myproperty" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/></xsd:sequence></xsd:extension></xsd:complexContent></xsd:complexType><xsd:element name="myfeature" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="Namespace2:myfeatureType"/></xsd:schema>`

so nothing unexpected

Comment: what do the two describeFeature requests in the schemas return?

Comment: see edited main question

Comment: is namespace2:feature actually buckow:graeber or Ahaus_neu:graeber? because those layers seem broken

Comment: no, it's a different one (brakel)

Comment: you have two brakel:graeber defined both of which are borken and you haven't changed your geoserver password from the well known default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this is a very well known bug for which we have no solution at the moment: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-4773